# change tag <h1>, if change page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some JavaScript code, and if the homepage or index (e.g. at [malaspulang.com](http://malaspulang.com)) the tag `<h1>` does not change. But if I change the page (e.g. at [malaspulang.com/lifestyle](http://malaspulang.com/lifestyle)), the tag `<h1>` will be replaced with `<h2>`.

This my code:

```
<div id="header" class="hide"><h1>this my title</h1></div>
<script>
if(window.URL === 'malaspulang.com'){

}else{

 $('#header').empty();
 $('#header').html('<h2>this my title</h2>');
}
</script>
```

In my homepage site, the tag `<h1>` should replace with `<h2>` I think that my code is true, but I am so confused with this code. So if anyone can help me, I will be happy :)

NB: If anyone that's code with PHP, you can tell me :)

Comment: I don't really get it...but why not just hard-code `<h1>` tags in the index, and `<h2>` for the rest?

Comment: actually i use wordpress site , and that to set SEO (in SEO 1 page 1 <h1> right?) , and thats my dinamic  code @Swellar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this :

```
<div class="hide" id="header">
  <h1>this my title</h1>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log(document.URL);//this optional , just display your link at now
      var uri= document.URL;
      if(uri == 'http://malaspulang.com/'){ //use full link from your site
      //do nothing , because logical true
      }else{
          $('#header').empty();
          $('#header').html('<h2>this my title</h2>');
      }
   });
</script>
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Access id using #header

```
$('#header').empty();
$('#header').html('<h2>this my title</h2>');
```

Comment: yup , I am type use that . actually the class already use <div class="hide" id="header">

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$('.header')` with `$('#header')`

`$('#header')` - targeting element with **id** attribute 'header'.

`$('.header')` - targeting element with **class** attribute 'header'.

Comment: yup , I am type use that . actually the class already use <div class="hide" id="header">

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `element` does *not* have a `class` defined. As seen here: `<div id="header"><h1>this my title</h1></div>`, it has the `id` of 'header' not the `class` of header. This means that your JavaScript needs to be calling for an `id` of 'header' and not a `class`.

Here is the code that will work:

`$('#header').html('<h2>This is my title</h2>');`

Comment: @Hatchwald Is it still not working? Many of these answers are saying about how you are using a `class` instead of an `id`. I see that you changed that, but if it is still not working, you may need to add more of an explanation/more code.

Comment: yup , that still not working :( , ok maybe I will ad some explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.URL` try to use `window.location.href` and also write complete url name: `http://malaspulang.com`

```
<div id="header" class="hide">
  <h1>this my title</h1>
</div>
<script>
if (window.location.href === 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/') { // current url
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = "<h1>this my title (h1)</h1>";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = "<h2>this my title (h2)</h2>";
}
</script>
```

You can also try it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/masoudarvishian/rcztuv96/)

Comment: ew , on th jsfiddle , that's display h2 if link true , if false ? how explain it ?

Comment: @Hatchwald if `window.location.href` equals to your home page it returns true and displays `h1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("body").hasClass("home")) {
    // don't do anything.
} else{
    // fire your code.
}
```

Comment: umm , "body" and "home" where are they from ?

Comment: could you add some explanations?

Answer (score -1):

Use `$('#header')` instead of `$('.header')` (select by `id`, not by `class`). And you do not need `$('.header').empty()`.

Comment: ew , actually my class ready use with <div id="header" class="hide">

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you want to say with it. Read @CyanCoding 's answer. He explained it well.

Comment: check my site at malaspulang.com , at home page inspect at logo in header , search <h2>